# Using elasticsearch generated ID's in kafka elasticsearch connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I noticed that documents indexed in elasticsearch using the kafka elasticsearch connector have their ids in the following format `topic+partition+offset`.

I would prefer to use id's generated by elasticsearch. It seems `topic+partition+offset` is not usually unique so I am [loosing data](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/loosing-data-in-elasticsearch/92433/16).

How can I change that?

Comment: Can you explain your use case more? Are you use the analytic or key-value mode of the connector? The `topic-partition-offset` should be unique for each record and the connector is publishing to Elastic each record that comes along. What data are you loosing? The forum you link to doesn't say what you are loosing.

Answer (score 2):

As Phil says in the comments -- `topic-partition-offset` should be unique, so I don't see how this is causing data loss for you.

Regardless - you can either let the connector generate the key (as you are doing), or you can define the key yourself (`key.ignore=false`). There is no other option.

You can use [Single Message Transformations](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms) with Kafka Connect to derive a key from the fields in your data. Based on your message in the Elasticsearch forum it looks like there is an `id` in your data - if that's going to be unique you could set that as your key, and thus as your Elasticsearch document ID too. Here's an example of defining a key with SMT:

```
# Add the `id` field as the key using Simple Message Transformations
transforms=InsertKey, ExtractId

# `ValueToKey`: push an object of one of the column fields (`id`) into the key
transforms.InsertKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.InsertKey.fields=id

# `ExtractField`: convert key from an object to a plain field
transforms.ExtractId.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.ExtractId.field=id
```

(via https://www.confluent.io/blog/building-real-time-streaming-etl-pipeline-20-minutes/)

Comment: Thanks @robin-moffat, I don't use a key in my messages. I tried some [transformations](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) to no success. I tried the TimestampRouter and RegexpRouter transforms.

I now use [datamountaineer elastic connector](https://github.com/datamountaineer/stream-reactor/) as it stores with elasticsearch generated IDs and I don't loose data any more.

It could be a problem with my kafka configuration though.

Answer (score 1):

@Robin Moffatt, as much as I see it, `topic-partition-offset` can cause duplicates in case that upgrade your kafka cluster, but not in rolling upgrade fashion but just replace cluster with cluster (which is sometime easier to replace). In this case you will experience data loss because of overwriting data.

Regarding to your excellent example, this can be the solution for many of the cases, but I'd add another option. Maybe you can add epoc timestamp element to the `topic-partition-offset` so this will be like this `topic-partition-offset-current_timestamp`.

What do you think?

Comment: How would you add the timestamp? using transforms?

Comment: I'd add it as hardcoded to the default `topic-partition-offset`.
But, if we can add it manually, this can solve that too.
But need to remember that the doc id wont by unique anymore, so we may loose the exactly once semantic.

Comment: We're probably diverging from the original question here, and possible your post is best added as a comment than an actual answer.

I agree that conceivably you could get dups, but not in normal operation - and if on is going to productionise something like this then arguably one is responsible for handling keys directly, if they are important to the app at hand.

Comment: You can log any improvement suggestions for the existing connector at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues.